# Are there alternatives for striptags filter?

Tags: 8, theming, entities

When printing a text field we just want to display the value. When printed as is in a twig template (`{{ content.field_subtitle }}`) we get the following output.

Currently we are attempting not to use the `|raw` filter so we are just using `{{ content.field_subtitle|render|striptags }}`.

Are there alternatives to this approach without having to create another twig template for the field? We are having a hard time finding an alternative.

Setup:

1. Basic page content type has field field_subtitle where type is text(plain)
2. no twig template has been created on the field, only the content type `node--page.html.twig`

Current setup in twig template

```
<div class="myclass__subtitle>
  {{ content.field_subtitle|render|striptags }}
</div>
```

Current output:

```
<div class="myclass__subtitle">    
  <div class="field field--name-field-subtitle field--type-string field--label-hidden field__item">Intrinsicly harness interactive functionalities.</div>
</div>
```

Desired output:

```
<div class="myclass__subtitle">    
  Intrinsicly harness interactive functionalities
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am vehemently against things like `render-array|render|striptags` etc. It feels very unnatural and un-Drupal. What you should do is create a field template that has no markup.

For example, either in `field.html.twig` which would affect all fields, or in `field--field-name.html.twig` or more specific variants, you can do this:

```
{#
/**
* @file
* Theme override to remove all field markup.
*/
#}

{% spaceless %}
{% for item in items %}
  {{ item.content }}
{% endfor %}
{% endspaceless %}
```

This will always render that field with no markup.

Comment: I agree about the striptags and raw filters, which is why I asked as I used the striptags to get by for now. So looks like the only option would be to create a field twig template for specific fields?

Comment: It’s bevwuse the markup is in the base field template. I usually start each project with a reset twig with the code above and fill in markup as needed in new templates.

Comment: that makes sense. I inherited the website, but I wished they had started like that with a clean slate as you have shown. Then we could create twig templates when more markup was needed.

Comment: Yeah, then its just cleaner and you know to look for templates instead of random ways things got rendered.

Comment: Worked great, thanks! Any idea [how to name templates for field types](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/294151/naming-convention-for-field-type-templates) to avoid code duplication?

Answer (score 2):

For a single value field, I often just do this: `{{ content.field_subtitle.0 }}`. This prints just the first delta, including whatever markup the field itself includes (e.g., works fine as well on reference fields or other more complex things) but does not use the field template at all.