# Naming convention for field type templates?

Tags: theming

It seems that the naming convention for field *types* is undocumented. Looking at the classy theme shows a seemingly arbitrary convention. For example, the Text (formatted, long, with summary) type as displayed in the UI is apparently named `field--text-with-summary.html.twig` as a template file.

What are the naming conventions for field types and how could I have determined them myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The naming convention for field templates is documented here, [Twig Template naming conventions](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/twig-template-naming-conventions#s-fields)

> - field--node--[field-name]--[content-type].html.twig
> - field--node--[field-name].html.twig
> - field--node--[content-type].html.twig
> - field--[field-name].html.twig
> - field--[field-type].html.twig field.html.twig

But `field--text-with-summary.html.twig` is one of those that is harder/trickier to figure out from just looking at the Field Type.

[image]

---

To make Drupal life easy for this, you can enable Twig Debug. See [Locating Template Files with Debugging](https://www.drupal.org/node/2358785)

Now when you inspect element with browser, you can see which template file is being used (the one with the "x") and what other available template file names (the ones with "*") you could use.

[image]

Comment: I've seen the documentation you linked to, and to clarify, it does not document the naming convention for field _types_, only the naming convention for templates. By the fact that one has to enable debugging mode and dig through logs to get to the type names, it seems that the type names are _undocumented._

Comment: @glenviewjeff the naming convention for field type is `[field-type]`, but like I said the `text-with-summary` is a tricky/gotcha one.